# Accessing Form controls from a module

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, hide, panel, member

I am trying to create a sub in a module that simply hides a lot of panels for a Form which is passed as a parameter to it. Basically, Ill have a button called **students** and a button called **subjects** and I want that when I click on the, lets says, **students** button ALL the panels I define in the function get hidden, and only the students panel remains visible.

When  I run this code I get :

```
System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'pnlAlumnos' on type 'Ventana_Principal' not found.'
```

#### Code in my module

```
Module Modulo_Comportamiento_Ventanas
 Public Sub Esconder_todos_los_paneles(ventana As Object)
        ventana.pnlAlumnos.Hide()
        ventana.pnlMaterias.Hide()
 End Sub
End Module
```

#### Code on the main Form click

```
Private Sub btnAlumnos_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAlumnos.Click
        Esconder_todos_los_paneles(Me)
        Me.pnlAlumnos.Show()
    End Sub
```

How can I modify my code in order to being able access the panels and hiding them?
Thanks in advance!

Note :  BTW, I know I can do this, but I want to know why it does not work the way I am doing it, I mean the below code looks horrible ( not that my other path looks any more nicer) :

```
Public Sub Esconder_todos_los_paneles()
        WindowsApp1.Ventana_Principal.pnlAlumnos.Hide()
        WindowsApp1.Ventana_Principal.pnlMaterias.Hide()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure `pnlAlumnos` is defined in `Ventana_Principal`? If so go to the designer of `Ventana_Principal` and click on the panel. In the properties window change `Modifiers` to Public.

Comment: @djv Thanks so much. That was it. :)